# getting access token for Youtube

Tags: android

I have generated the Client ID, Client Secret, redirect-url and code by the help of this API Documentation.

https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_oauth2#OAuth2_Installed_Applications_Flow

I am doing same as above Document, but gives the following error.

> Error: invalid_request
>
> Required parameter is missing: response_type

Answer (score 0):

Currently for the version 3, the implementation is quite easy. Have a look at the [Google Task](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/source/browse/tasks-android-sample/src/main/java/com/google/api/services/samples/tasks/android/TasksSample.java?repo=samples) sample.